# How to make points in chartjs draggable?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, chart.js

## Question

I'm looking to make 3 points on a graph draggable between 0 and 100. I'm looking to do this in React with [ChartJS](https://www.chartjs.org/) via [react-chartjs-2](https://github.com/jerairrest/react-chartjs-2).

[Here is a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Coltin/7nf6dmhh/2/) with everything setup (js also below).

## Extra Info

The fiddle uses some random version of react-chartjs-2 because I couldn't figure out how to import. On my local setup I use `import { Line } from 'react-chartjs-2';` but I'm not sure how to do that in jsfiddle. Webdev is super new to me.

## What have I tried so far?

- I tried using a few chartjs plugins ([like this one](https://github.com/chrispahm/chartjs-plugin-dragData)) that claimed
  to do draggable points, but I couldn't figure out how to get them
  working in React. This might be the easiest solutin.
- I tried adding my own event listeners for mouseDown/Up/Enter/Leave,
  but I was unable to attach these to the actual points. If I just have
  access to `<Line />` is there a way in React for me to attach to the
  points themselves? If I could get the coordinates and have these
  events, I could kludge together a solution.
- I tried searching on the chartjs and react-chartjs-2 docs, but I
  couldn't find anything that would let me drag, or attach the right
  listeners.

## Code

```
var Line = reactChartjs2.Line;

const options = {
  tooltips: {enabled: true},
  scales: {
    xAxes: [{
      gridLines: {display: false, color: 'grey',},
      ticks: {fontColor: '#3C3C3C', fontSize: 14,},
    }],
    yAxes: [{
      scaleLabel: {display: true, labelString: 'Color Strength', fontSize: 14,},
      ticks: {
        display: true,
        min: -5,
        max: 100,
        scaleSteps: 50,
        scaleStartValue: -50,
        maxTicksLimit: 4,
        fontColor: '#9B9B9B',
        padding: 30,
        callback: point => (point < 0 ? '' : point),
      },
      gridLines: {
        display: false,
        offsetGridLines: true,
        color: '3C3C3C',
        tickMarkLength: 4,
      },
    }],
  },
};

class DraggableGraph extends React.Component {
    state = {
    dataSet: [0, 0, 0],
    labels: ['red', 'green', 'blue'],
    };

    render() {
        const data = {
      labels: this.state.labels,
      datasets: [{
        data: this.state.dataSet,
        borderColor: '9B9B9B',
        borderWidth: 1,
        pointRadius: 10,
        pointHoverRadius: 10,
        pointBackgroundColor: '#609ACF',
        pointBorderWidth: 0,
        spanGaps: false,
      }],
    };

    return (
      <div>
        <Line
          data={data}
          options={options}
          legend={{display: false}}
          plugins={{}}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<DraggableGraph />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

Comment: Have you tried using highcharts ?  It has draggable plots chart.. example https://jsfiddle.net/highcharts/AyUbx/?utm_source=website&utm_medium=embed&utm_campaign=AyUbx  or you can even check d3 chart - https://bl.ocks.org/denisemauldin/538bfab8378ac9c3a32187b4d7aed2c2

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions @johnsam. Highcharts seems cost prohibitive so I think that's out, though it does look very nice. D3 chart doesn't seem all that different from implementing charts myself in React. Maybe I'll have to look at the example longer to see if I can easily make the graph nice. The Fiddle is a very cut down version of what I ultimately want and having to implement everything in D3 may be a pain compared to being able to make ChartJs draggable.

Comment: I had a lot of difficulty with ChartJS (`react-chartjs-2`) and ended up moving over to CanvasJS. They have draggable features out-of-the-box: https://canvasjs.com/javascript-charts/interactive-draggable-chart/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this by using [chartjs-plugin-dragData](https://github.com/chrispahm/chartjs-plugin-dragData). You have to set **dragData: true** within **options** object to use this plugin in chart js. Here I have provided updated code.

```
  var Line = reactChartjs2.Line;

const options = {
  tooltips: {enabled: true},
  scales: {
    xAxes: [{
      gridLines: {display: false, color: 'grey',},
      ticks: {fontColor: '#3C3C3C', fontSize: 14,},
    }],
    yAxes: [{
      scaleLabel: {display: true, labelString: 'Color Strength', fontSize: 14,},
      ticks: {
        display: true,
        min: -5,
        max: 100,
        scaleSteps: 50,
        scaleStartValue: -50,
        maxTicksLimit: 4,
        fontColor: '#9B9B9B',
        padding: 30,
        callback: point => (point < 0 ? '' : point),
      },
      gridLines: {
        display: false,
        offsetGridLines: true,
        color: '3C3C3C',
        tickMarkLength: 4,
      },
    }],
  },
  legend:{
  display: false
  },
  dragData: true,
  onDragStart: function (e) {
    console.log(e)
  },
  onDrag: function (e, datasetIndex, index, value) {
    console.log(datasetIndex, index, value)
  },
  onDragEnd: function (e, datasetIndex, index, value) {
    console.log(datasetIndex, index, value)
  }
};

class DraggableGraph extends React.Component {
    state = {
    dataSet: [0, 0, 0],
    labels: ['red', 'green', 'blue'],
    };

    render() {
        const data = {
      labels: this.state.labels,
      datasets: [{
        data: this.state.dataSet,
        borderColor: '9B9B9B',
        borderWidth: 1,
        pointRadius: 10,
        pointHoverRadius: 10,
        pointBackgroundColor: '#609ACF',
        pointBorderWidth: 0,
        spanGaps: false,
      }],
    };

    return (
      <div>
        <Line
          data={data}
          options={options}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<DraggableGraph />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

https://jsfiddle.net/4mdenzjx/